# How to insert accented characters in ASCII-encoded Rd files?

Tags: r, package, latex, ascii, rd

Can LaTeX escapes for accents be used in `Rd` files? I tried the standard `\'e` and many variants (`\'{e}`, `{\'e}`, `\\'e`, `\\'{e}`, `{\\'e}`, etc.), but none is rendered as an accented character in the PDF or HTML output.

I want my References section (i.e. `\references{}`) to be rendered with accented characters, but I do not want to type non-ASCII characters in my `Rd` files. Is there good/recommended practice? Should I simply replace non-ASCII characters with their ASCII equivalents (é → e, ø → o)?

To be clear, I know it is possible to type accented characters (e.g., `é`) directly in UTF-8-encoded files, but I would prefer to keep ASCII-encoded files.

This question is *not* about:

- [how to type special/accented letters in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8857)
- [how to use UTF-8 in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/370278)
- [accents/special characters in R Markdown](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/541298)

or variants.

##### Minimal test package

Package structure:

```plaintext
test
test/man
test/man/one.Rd
test/R
test/R/one.R
test/DESCRIPTION
```

`test/man/one.Rd`:

```tex
\name{one}
\alias{one}
\title{Get One}
\description{Accents are not rendered: \'e \'{e} {\'e} \\'e \\'{e} {\\'e}}
\usage{
one()
}
```

`test/R/one.R`:

```r
one <- function() 1
```

`test/DESCRIPTION`:

```yaml
Package: test
Version: 0.1
Title: Test
Author: Nobody
Maintainer: Nobody <no@body.org>
Description: Test.
License: GPL-3
```

Build, check, and install with:

```sh
$ R CMD build test
$ R CMD check test_0.1.tar.gz
$ R CMD INSTALL test_0.1.tar.gz
```

Comment: I posted the question on stackoverflow.com rather than on tex.stackexchange.com because (i) the question is more about R than LaTex (i.e. `\'e` fails in Rd files but works in LaTex); (ii) a search with "Rd files" gives no relevant results on tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If you encode your files in utf8, there should not be problems with sharing them between different systems.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'm afraid there is a confusion here: I'am not talking about rmarkdown (i.e. Rmd file) but about standard documentation of R package (i.e. Rd files) build by R CMD build.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz No, it don't. I get `&eacute;` in the PDF output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Rd` syntax is only LaTeX-*like*: it supports a limited set of macros, but these are not guaranteed to behave like their LaTeX counterparts, if any exist. Conversely, very few LaTeX macros have `Rd` equivalents.

[This](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Rd-format) section of the Writing R Extensions manual describes most of the built-in `Rd` macros. Tables 1, 2, and 3 of [this](https://developer.r-project.org/parseRd.pdf) technical paper provide a complete list.

[This](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Encoding) section of WRE addresses encoding specifically.
Use of non-ASCII characters in `Rd` files is supported, provided that you declare an appropriate encoding, either in the files themselves (via `\enc` and `\encoding`) or in `DESCRIPTION` (via the `Encoding` field). However, restriction to ASCII characters is encouraged:

> Wherever possible, avoid non-ASCII chars in `Rd` files, and even symbols such as ‘<’, ‘>’, ‘$’, ‘^’, ‘&’, ‘|’, ‘@’, ‘~’, and ‘*’ outside ‘verbatim’ environments (since they may disappear in fonts designed to render text).

The recommended way to obtain non-ASCII characters in rendered help  *without* including non-ASCII characters in your `Rd` files is to use [conditional text](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Conditional-text). `\ifelse` allows you to provide raw LaTeX for PDF help pages, raw HTML for HTML help pages, and verbatim text for plain text help pages:

```
\ifelse{latex}{\out{\'{e}}}{\ifelse{html}{\out{&eacute;}}{e}}
```

That is quite verbose, so I would suggest [defining your own macro(s)](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#User_002ddefined-macros) in `man/macros/macros.Rd`. You can do this with `\newcommand` and `\renewcommand`:

```
\newcommand{\eacute}{\ifelse{latex}{\out{\'{e}}}{\ifelse{html}{\out{&eacute;}}{e}}}
```

Then you can use `\eacute{}` freely in all of your `Rd` files. To check that text is rendered the way you want in all formats, install the package and run `help(topic, help_type=)`, with `help_type` equal to `"text"`, `"html"`, or `"pdf"`.

Comment: Thank you for your answser and the canonical references. I edited my question to precise my use case (references with non-ASCII characters). Do you have any advice/What would you do?

Comment: If I really wanted ASCII-encoded `Rd` files, then I would use `\ifelse` to include non-ASCII characters in the rendered PDF and HTML help, as explained in my answer.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks again !

Answer (score -1):

Using math mode it works. Not sure 100% if this is what you are looking for.

Here are some examples:

```
  \'{e} {\'e} \\'e \\'{e} {\\'e}

$\acute{e}$

$\grave{e}$

$\tilde{e}$
```

PDF output:

```
’{e} {’e} \‘e \’{e} {\’e}
é
è
ẽ
```

Update:

```
\newcommand\latexcode[1]{#1}

\latexcode{\'{a}}

Thoma\latexcode{\'{s}}
```

That works Thomas !

Comment: Thank you! It seems more like a trick than a proper solution though...

Comment: @AugtPelle The font as well as the kerning will be wrong

Comment: I just tested in the `test` package provided in my first post and it fails: `R CMD build` returns `Warning: /tmp/xxx/xxx/test/man/test.Rd:10: unknown macro '\acute'` and  accents are not rendered in the PDF or in the HTML output (I get `$\acutee$`). Does it work in an Rd file or in a standard LaTex file for you?

Comment: @Thomas please test my last update. Turns out there is a problem Between Latex and Rmarkdown, how the markdown engine works, passing to Latex what it recognize as Latex code. You can find more details here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541298/rmarkdown-french-accents-special-characters

Comment: Thank you for your update. While the issue you linked is close, I'm afraid there is a confusion here: I'am not talking about rmarkdown (i.e. **Rmd** file) but about standard documentation of R package (i.e. **Rd** files) build by `R CMD build`. Can I really define a new command in a **Rd** file?